# Meaning of 'firehouse' & 'pour forth from' in this news article

Tags: word-meaning

What do *firehouse* and *pour forth from* mean in this sentence?

> But according to recent polling, even the stellar economy can't save
>   Trump from the **firehouse** of irredeemable qualities that **pour forth from** him on a daily and, indeed, hourly basis.

Here's the link of the article in which I saw this sentence:
[Trump is so abhorrent, even a stellar economy can't save him](https://www.dailykos.com/stories/2019/5/27/1859471/-Trump-is-so-abhorrent-even-a-stellar-economy-can-t-save-him)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me like a typo of "firehose":

> [fire hose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fire_hose#English):
>
> 2. (idiomatic) Any fast, heavy stream (e.g. of information).
>      *She felt she was standing in front of a fire hose of instructions, trying to absorb them all with a sponge.*

In this context, it just means that Trump constantly exhibits massive amounts of irredeemable qualities, just like a firehose constantly pours out massive amount of water.